# Random custom.css file took over my scss code

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

My scss code stopped working. I identified the problem - two css files: `custom.css.css` and `custom.css.css.map`. I'm not using bootstrap, just ror. How do I make ruby ignore them? Or shouldn't I? The layout looks exactly the same, the code is easier to read (but not neat enough for my liking).

Comment: Did you find these files in the directory or you noticed them being loaded in the browser?

Comment: the former. hiding in my stylesheets folder.

Comment: Sounds strange, because even if you add an assets gem to your Gemfile this wouldn't generate files in your directories. The assets files of an assets gem are stored inside the gem space.

Comment: I would suggest you first find out how the css files came into project. Only then can you decide to have or not have these css files. Since the naming is also `custom`, it is verly likely some human(not a gem) has added these files.

Comment: Oh god my repo is private how would that happen? A hacker took pity on my lousy code?

Answer (score 0):

.map files are called source maps and they are used by browsers to display css files. I guess you are using SASS or LESS as you having a .map file generated. You may need to enable source maps in browsers to display the styles correctly. I hope following urls might help you.

[Sass source files in Google Chrome](http://blog.vhyza.eu/blog/2013/09/22/debugging-rails-4-coffeescript-and-sass-source-files-in-google-chrome/)

[Sass Source Maps + Chrome = Magic](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/sass-source-maps-chrome-magic)